# Calculate integral $\int x^{1 \over x} dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Are there any known methods so that we can calculate the integral below :
$$
\int x^{1 \over x} dx
$$

Comment: Look for "Sophomore's dream" here on MSE. It has been asked many times.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Sophomore's dream is an identity involving $\int_0^1 x^{-x}\mathrm dx$, not $\int x^{1/x}\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 3):

Using $$\bullet\; x = e^{\ln x}$$ and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; n\cdot \ln(m) = \ln(m)^n$$

We can write $$\displaystyle x^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\ln(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}} = e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet e^x = 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...........\infty$$

So we get $$\displaystyle e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}} = 1+\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\cdot \left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3!}\cdot \left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^3+........\infty$$

Now $$\displaystyle \int e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}dx = \int \left[1+\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\cdot \left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3!}\cdot \left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)^3+........\infty\right]dx$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream